# Authentication using different database with the help of EF instead of application DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication

**Problem Statement**
I've some applications running and potential users are same for both applications so right now they need to signup on both applications separately and create password for both.

If someone forget the password or someone want to reset his/her password they need to perform action on both applications.

**What I want?**

I want to create a different database for authentication and want to use that database for both application at the time of authenticating user.

Is it possible using same approach I am using Entity framework how can i use to open a connection with different database(Central DB). Is there any tutorial or any link that could help me ? what should be the best approach to implement this ?

My Current code

```
public ActionResult Login(Login login)
    {
        var result = user.FindUser(login.Email);
        if (result==null)
        {
            ViewData["Con"] = "IncorrectEmail";
            ViewBag.data = "login";
            return View();
        }
        if(result.Password==null || result.ConfirmPassword==null)
        {
            ViewData["Con"] = "PasswordNull";
            ViewBag.data = "login";
            return View();
        }
        var deptName = deptRepos.SelectByID(result.DepartmentID);
        var role = (roleRep.SelectByID(result.RoleID).RoleType).ToUpper();
        string pass = user.Decrypt(result.Password);


        if (login.Password.ToLower().Trim() != pass || login.Password==null)
        {
            ViewData["Con"] = "IncorrectPassword";
            ViewBag.data = "login";
            return View();
        }
        //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] = result.Name;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Email"] = login.Email;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Password"] = login.Password;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Department"] = deptName.Name;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["DepartmentID"] = deptName.ID;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Designation"] = result.Designation;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Role"] = role;
```

this is my webconfig

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="EmailConfiguration" connectionString="data source=.;    initial catalog=EmailConfiguration;persist security info=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;    Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This is the current scenario with single DB.

Comment: Have you tried adding one more connection string and working with it ?

Comment: not yet . Just want to know that should be the best approach and if i can find some links for the same